# Ruby ternary operator and elsif

Tags: ruby

I want to write `if...elsif` statement using ternary syntax.
Can I add another check for `ARGV[1]` inside this statement ?

```
test-expression ? if-true-expression : if-false-expression
ARGV[1] == "home" ? (installabra) : (puts menuInstall)
```

- this works

Comment: You mean a nested ternary operator?

Comment: You can, but its frowned upon.

Comment: clarify your need please?

Comment: Avoid using compound/complex ternary statements. They might be idiomatic in C and Perl, but not in Ruby. It's easy enough to create a similar result using `if/elsif/else/end` and `case`. It comes down to being a readability/maintenance thing.

Answer (score 10):

Anything you can do with `if...elsif...else...end`

```
if cond1
  stmt1
elsif cond2
  stmt2
elseif cond3
  stmt3
else
  stmt4
end
```

you can do with nested ternary operators:

```
cond1 ? stmt1 : (cond2 ? stmt2 : (cond3 ? stmt3 : stmt4)))
```

or with even less clarity, omitting the parentheses:

```
cond1 ? stmt1 : cond2 ? stmt2 : cond3 ? stmt3 : stmt4
```

But consider which code is clearer and easier to maintain.

In your question, you asked if you could put another test for `ARGV[1]` in the nested conditions.  If your conditions are always testing `ARGV[1]` for equality, then a case statement is superior:

```
case ARGV[1]
when 'home'
  installabra
when 'away'
  goaway
else
  puts menuInstall
end
```

Comment: @mcfinnigan We can hope that experience will be a better teacher than I am.

Comment: @cnav, It occurs to me that a `case` statement might work well for what you're doing.  Please see the edit above.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% I have understood your question fully.... does the following achieve what you are after?

```
x = ARGV[0].to_i
y = if x == 1 then "one"
    elsif x == 2 then "two"
    else "unknown"
    end

puts "x = #{x}, y = #{y}"
```

This goes beyond the ternary syntax but gives you more flexibility.

Output:

```
$ ruby test.rb 2
x = 2, y = two
```

Comment: A `case` statement would be a better fit than `if/elsif/else/end`.