# syntax of if/elsif inline statement with ruby

Tags: ruby, if-statement

Is posible declare an `if elsif` statement inline?

Like `x > 2 ? "Greater" : "Equal or lower"`

```
if x == 2 
  puts "Equal"
elsif x > 2 
  puts "Greater"
else
  puts "Lower"
```

Comment: You want a quaternary operator? ;-)

Comment: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478357/ruby-ternary-operator-and-elsif) might be of help

Comment: What do you mean by "declare"? You don't need to declare anything to use a conditional expression in Ruby, you can just use it. What do you mean by "`if elsif`statement"? There are no statements in Ruby, only expressions. What do you mean by "inline"? Ruby doesn't have a concept of "inlining" in the language (although many Ruby compilers will of course perform inlining as an optimization). Also, inlining only applies to method calls.

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer? You don't want to see others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can write

```
x == 2 ? "Equal" : x > 2 ? "Greater" : "Lower"
```

But I would recommend against writing such lines because IMO they are hard to read and to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do it two ways:

1. with semicolons

   ```
   if x == 2; "Equal"; elsif x > 2; "Greater"; else; "Lower"; end
   ```
2. with `then`:

   ```
   if x == 2 then "Equal" elsif x > 2 then "Greater" else "Lower" end
   ```

Also keep in mind that `if/unless` are expressions with a return value, for example:

```
val = if x == 2 then "Equal"
      elsif x > 2 then "Greater"
      else "Lower"
      end
```

or

```
puts(if x == 2 then "Equal"
  elsif x > 2 then "Greater"
  else "Lower" end
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Three more ways:

```
(x == 2 && "Equal") || (x > 2 && "Greater") || "Lower"
```

```
case x <=> 2 when -1 then "Lower" when 0 then "Equal" else "Greater" end
```

```
["Equal", "Greater", "Lower" ][x <=> 2]
```